# Cycle through existing users until one isn't found

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, if-statement

I'm just messing about really but ran into a problem. I'm trying to create a username when a user clicks on a div within the page.

I want it to store the usernames in an array. If the username already exists in the array I want it to re-run the function to  create a new username until it finds one that doesn't exist then put that into the array.

I just can't seem to workout how to achieve this. Could anyone help please? Thank You

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(function() {
    var usernames = [];

    function createUser() {
      var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
      var newUser = "Username" + i;
      return newUser;
    }

    $(".CreateUser").click(function() {
      var newUser = createUser();
      if (jQuery.inArray(newUser, usernames) !== -1) {
        newUser = createUser();
        console.log("User Exists");
      } else {
        usernames.push(newUser);
        $(".Usernames").append("<br>" + newUser);
        console.log(usernames);
        console.log("User Added");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: You could do this recursively. Ie. if a username matches an existing one call the function again incrementing `i` by one. This obviously won't be performant and should never be used in the real world, though. In a real world example you'd use something like a GUID or a random string seeded by the date/time to create a unique identifier.

Comment: That's kinda what i'm wanting to do but not sure how to go about it. This project is just for myself and also just for something to do. I like making stupid little things and that. I'm sure you can understand :P. I'm not the strongest of coders at all but I do really enjoy it. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Note that `$(document).ready(function() {` and `jQuery(function() {` do exactly the same thing. There's no reason to wrap one inside the other.

Comment: Oh yeah, bloody hell. :P, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use while loop , but I don't recommend it with your function , so better way to make a function with an initial value , so each time you click on the button , the username will be changed .

```
function createUser(i) {
  var newUser = "Username" + i;
  return newUser;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  var usernames = [];
  //initial value 
  var i = 1;

  $(".CreateUser").click(function () {
    var newUser = createUser(i);
   //increase the initial value so next username will be increased by 1
    i += 1;
    usernames.push(newUser);
    $(".Usernames").append("<br>" + newUser);
    console.log(usernames);
    console.log("User Added");
  });
});
```

check this [example](https://codepen.io/remon/pen/pojNMNN?editors=1111)
I made it as simple as I can .

to check in an array , you can use includes method

```
var user_in_array = usernames.includes(newUser) // returns true of false
```

to generate a random string and check if it exists or not

```
function createUser() {
  var random_txt = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
  var newUser = "Username_" + random_txt;
  return newUser;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  var usernames = [];
  //initial value

  $(".CreateUser").click(function () {
    var newUser = createUser();
    //increase the initial value so next username will be increased by 1

    while (usernames.includes(newUser)) {
      newUser = createUser();
    }
    usernames.push(newUser);
    $(".Usernames").append("<br>" + newUser);
    console.log(usernames);
    console.log("User Added");
  });
});
```

working example [here](https://codepen.io/remon/pen/YzyNKqX)

Comment: That is great and will work obviously. But i'm interested in what the solution is for the problem I have. I want to be able to check if that username exists and if so repeat the function again until it doesn't then put that into the array. Thank you again for your post.

Comment: Checking an array, thank you i didn't know about this way. Really helps :).

Comment: @SomethingGood , check updated answer , I made a live example

Comment: That does work well. But like I said I want it so it's random. So it would need to check if the user already exists. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @SomethingGood I updated my answer to include a random text generator and to check  the array

Comment: That is beautiful. That had done exactly what I was aiming for. So simple when I look at it now :P. Thank you again for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Could be time for a `do/while` loop:

```
do {
  var newUser = createUser();
} while (jQuery.inArray(newUser, usernames) !== -1)

usernames.push(newUser);
```

The loop will keep creating new random usernames until it finds one which does not exist in the array.  Then it breaks the loop and pushes that last name into the array.

Comment: Fun fact: I've only used a do/while loop in production once in 12 years.  It was the best day.